# Undefined-Behavior at its best, is it -boundary break? -bad pointer arithmetic? Or just -ignore of aliasing?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic, strict-aliasing

I'm working now for some weeks with c99 focusing undefined behaviour.
I wanted to test some strange code while trying to respect the rules.
The result was this code:

(plz forgive me the variable names, i had eaten a clown)

```
int main(int arg, char** argv)
{

    unsigned int uiDiffOfVars;
    int LegalPointerCast1, LegalPointerCast2, signedIntToRespectTheRules;
    char StartVar;//Only use to have an adress from where we can move on
    char *TheAccesingPointer;
    int iTargetOfPointeracces;

    iTargetOfPointeracces= 0x55555555;

    TheAccesingPointer = (char *) &StartVar;
    LegalPointerCast2 = (int) &StartVar;
    LegalPointerCast1 = (int) &iTargetOfPointeracces;

    if ((0x80000000 & LegalPointerCast2) != (0x80000000 & LegalPointerCast1))
    {
        //as im not sure in how far 
        //"— Apointer is converted to other than an integer or pointer type (6.5.4)." is treating unsigned integers,
        //im checking this way.
        printf ("try it on next machine!\r\n");
        return 1;
    }


    if ((abs (LegalPointerCast1) > abs (LegalPointerCast2)))
        uiDiffOfVars = abs (LegalPointerCast1) - abs (LegalPointerCast2);
    else
        uiDiffOfVars = abs (LegalPointerCast2) - abs (LegalPointerCast1);

    LegalPointerCast2 = (int) TheAccesingPointer;
    signedIntToRespectTheRules = abs ((int) uiDiffOfVars);

    if ((abs (LegalPointerCast1) > abs (LegalPointerCast2)))
        TheAccesingPointer = (char *)(LegalPointerCast2 + signedIntToRespectTheRules);
    else
        TheAccesingPointer = (char *)(LegalPointerCast2 - signedIntToRespectTheRules);

     printf ("%c\r\n", *TheAccesingPointer);//Will the output be an 'U' ?

    return 0;
}
```

So this code is undefined behavior at its best.
I get different results, whether I'm not accessing any memory-area, that i don't own, nor accessing any uninitialized memory.
(afaik)

The first critical rule was, I'm not allowed to add or subtract pointer which lets them leaving their array bounds. But I'm allowed to cast a pointer into integer, there I'm able calculate with, as I want, am I not?

My second assumption was as I'm allowed to assign a pointer an address thats valid, its a valid operation to assign this calculated address to a pointer.
Since I'm acting with a char pointer, there is also no break of strict aliasing rules, as a char* is allowed to alias anything.

So which rule is broken, that this causes UB?

are single Variables also to be understood as "Arrays", and I'm breaking this rule?

> — Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
>   integer type produces a result that does not point into, or just beyond, the same array
>   object (6.5.6).

If so, I'm also allowed to do this?

```
int var;
int *ptr;
ptr = &var;
ptr = ptr + 1;
```

Because the result is almost pretty sure undefined behavior.
compiling with MSVC2010 it puts out the expected "U",
but on freeBSD using clang and gcc I get depending on optimization level pretty funny and different results each time.
(what in my eyes shouldn't be as far the bahavior is defined).

So any ideas what is causing this nasal dragons?

Comment: Remember that even on today's 64-bit platforms `int` is still 32 bits while addresses are 64 bits. So storing an address in an `int` will most definitely lead to undefined behavior. If you want an integer to store a pointer, you should use `intptr_t`.

Comment: yeah i know. but as I explicit cast this shouldn't be the problem, and even if, there also where difference between the single 32bit compilations

Comment: Yes it's most definitely a problem. When you do e.g. `LegalPointerCast2AkaBountyPlacer = (int) &TheCharedyBitch` on a 64-bit system you silently drop the top 32 bits of the address of `TheCharedyBitch`, and if you later use `LegalPointerCast2AkaBountyPlacer` as an address it will now most likely point to somewhere completely different.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg as i already said, I'm agreeing you, but thats not the point of my question (I eddited the Info out now)

Comment: Could you go through your example code, and replace the variable names with short, meaningful ones, so that it's easier to grok?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I did it. But they were meaningfull, they even told a story about assasination. But nvm.

Comment: @Downvoters explanation plz? I mean this is undefined behavior and I dont know why. so what about tell me why, if its such a stupid question?!

Answer (score 2):

You are basically running into paragraph 6.3.2.3 Pointer ad 5 in conversion from `int` to `char*` in the assignment to `TheAccesingPointer`.

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

The use of all `abs` functions makes it very dependent on the actual implementation what happens. Basically it will only work if `iTargetOfPointeracces` has a higher address than `StartVar`. If you lose all occurrences of `abs` I think you will get `'U'` on most if not all architectures and with most if not all compilers.

Ironically this is not undefined behavior but implementation defined behavior. But when you don't get `'U'` the `TheAccesingPointer` is not pointing to an entity of the referenced type, most likely it is not pointing to an entity at all.

If it is not pointing to an entity then (of course) you will run into undefined behavior when dereferencing it in the `printf` following paragraph 6.5.3.2 ad 4

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

Let's elaborate two scenarios where all addresses on the stack have bit 31 set, which is quite common under Linux.

Scenario A: Suppose `&StartVar < &iTargetOfPointeracces` then

```
  abs(LegalPointerCast1) - abs(LegalPointerCast2)
= LegalPointerCast2 - LegalPointerCast1 (by both < 0)
= (char*)(&StartVar) - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces)
< 0 (by &StartVar < &iTargetOfPointeracces)
So uiDiffOfVars = (char*)(&StartVar) - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces)
and signedIntToRespectTheRules = -uiDiffOfVars (by (int)uiDiffOfVars < 0)
thus  TheAccesingPointer
= (char *)(&StartVar + (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces) - (char*)(&StartVar))
= (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces)
```

So in this scenario you will get `'U'`.

Scenario B: Suppose `&StartVar > &iTargetOfPointeracces` then

```
  abs(LegalPointerCast1) - abs(LegalPointerCast2)
= LegalPointerCast2 - LegalPointerCast1 (by both < 0)
= (char*)(&StartVar) - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces)
> 0 (by &StartVar > &iTargetOfPointeracces)
So uiDiffOfVars = (char*)(&StartVar) - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces)
and signedIntToRespectTheRules = uiDiffOfVars (by (int)uiDiffOfVars > 0)
thus TheAccesingPointer
= (char *)(&StartVar + (char*)(&StartVar) - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces))
= (char *)(2*(char*)&StartVar - (char*)(&iTargetOfPointeracces))
```

In this scenario it is very unlikely that `TheAccesingPointer` is pointing to some entity, so undefined behavior is triggered in dereferencing this pointer. So my point is that the calculation of `TheAccesingPointer` is *implementation defined*, where the above calculations are very common. If the computed pointer is not pointing to `iTargetOfPointeracces`, as in scenario B, *undefined behavior* is triggered.

Different optimization levels may result in a different order of `StartVar' and`iTargetOfPointeracces' on the stack and that may explain the different result for different optimization levels.

I don't think single variables count as an array.

Comment: Well, I would suggest, you'r wrong. I'm masking out and comparing the first bit, so I'm checking for they both have the same sign. And I would also say, it's not just implementation defined behavior, because I'm getting in gcc different results in -O1 and -O3 so this cant be the result of implementation defined behavior, can it?

Comment: @Zaibis I've worked out two different scenarios, one triggering undefined behavior and the other doesn't. I hope that clarifies the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: I eddited the code. As I was trying out your Suggestion may be the reason. So I'm respecting now its a neg address or a positive address. And the result was pretty funny. Even under windows now the result wasn't "U" so i backuped to previous version and the result still wasn't "U" anymore. So this code has undefined behavior. and your suggestion sadly was wrong. Maybe another idea, in review of the new facts? E: -> the last time I runned same code on Windows it was the "U" but now in both cases the result changed doesn't matter about both address have neg or pos value.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation may only define `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` if it can guarantee two things:

1. the act of converting a valid or null pointer to one of those types will yield defined behavior;
2. If some value of that type, q, is numerically equal to the result of such conversion, and if the object identified by the converted pointer still exists, converting the value of type q back to the original pointer type will yield a pointer which compares equal to the original.

If uintptr_t is a 64-bit unsigned integer type, code may convert any valid pointer to uintptr_t and operate upon it just like any other 64-bit unsigned integer, without regard for the size of the original object or anything else.  On the other hand, converting the result of such conversion back to the pointer type would, from the point of view of the Standard, only yield defined behavior in cases where the resulting number matched the result of an earlier conversion from a still-valid pointer to uintptr_t.

Note, btw, that many implementations document the relationship between pointers and `uintptr_t` values to an extent far beyond what the Standard requires, but that does not imply that code making use of such knowledge will actually work.  For example, given the code:

```
static int x,y;
int test(void)
{
  int *p = outsideFunction(&x);
  y=1;
  *p=5;
  return y;
}
```

some impementations might document means via which a programmer could ascertain the relative displacements of x and y.  Even such implementations, however, might generate code that assumes that the write to *p can't possibly affect y since it is a static object which never has its address taken.

Comment: I don't actually get how this is answering my question. Sorry if I don't see the relation. But I jsut read your answer describing behaving of `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. But I don't see where it contradicsts with my code.

Comment: @dhein: The only implementations that are required by the Standard to meaningfully define the behavior of any code that converts pointer types to integer types are those which define `uintptr_t` and/or `intptr_t`.  Those implementations must behave as descried in my answer.  Otherwise, the behavior of any code which makes use of such casts will be reliant upon what guarantees, if any, the implementation can offer beyond what the Standard requires.

Comment: Ok, but could you demonstrate where from the standard this is comming from?

Comment: @dhein: The definitions of `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` describe what is guaranteed about those types.  Otherwise, the Standard allows implementations to define the relationship between pointers and numeric  vallues as they see fit, and provides that if a pointer is converted to an integer type which is too small for its "numeric" value the behavior is undefined.  Nothing in the Standard requires that implementations have to support a numeric type large enough to hold pointers, and the Standard recognizes the possibility that some implementations may not have one (snce `uint64_t` is optional).